# how does the so-called LOOK algorithm work for elevators

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

I'm building a elevator simulator in Swift right now and find it very complicated.

The main problem for me is I put all the requests in an array and sort it in either order regarding its direction of movement at the point the call was made.

But how to improve it that whenever new calls come the elevator adjusts its moving pattern so that the average waiting time is kept minimum? (namely what's working behind the LOOK algorithm)

Hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: If the elevator is going up, keep going up until there are no more requests on higher floors. Then change directions so the elevator is going down, and keep going down until there are no more requests on lower floors.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOOK_algorithm ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_algorithm